# Unable to clear the fileds after saving the data using apex code

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

```
//Apex page
 <apex:page controller="MyController" tabStyle="Account"  showChat="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Congratulations  {!$User.FirstName}">
            You belong to Account Name: <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
          Annual Revenue:  <apex:inputField value="{!account.AnnualRevenue}" required="true"/>
           <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/></apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My code is saving the data to my account successfully.But,the fields are not clearing until i press refresh button

```
//Apex Class

public class MyController {


    private Account account; public Account getAccount(){
    if(account == null)
    account=new Account();
    return account;
    }
    public PageReference save(){
    insert account;
    return null;
    }
}

My code is saving the data to my account successfully.But,the fields are not clearing until i press refresh button. 

So, anyone can guide me to clear the page after saving my data?
```

Comment: It should refresh you page i cant see the problem. However did you tried to use rerender attribute of apex:commandButton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the account value is still available in the view state.
add another line in the pagereference method and that should help. something like this:

```
public PageReference save(){
   insert account;
   account=null;
   return null;
}
```